# how to stop Extrainfo appearing in cover letter?

Tags: moderncv

I am using Texmaker to update my CV, but i am having problem with the \extrainfo. I am using moderncv documentclass and moderncvstyle {classic}. I want extrainfo to appear in my curriculum but not in my cover letter. Latex Template code is given below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title} 
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org} 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
```

Then code goes on with section, subsections for CV until we arrive at the coverleter part

```
    \recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
    \date{January 01, 1984}
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
    \closing{Yours faithfully,}
    \enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}  
    \makelettertitle
    \makeletterclosing
    \end{document}
```

What i get in Cv and cover letter is shown below:
[image]

Same 'Additional information' appear in the cover letter as:[image]

Now I want to keep this Additional information in my Cv but want to remove it from the cover letter. Any help????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of patching `\makelettertitle`, you can just set the "additional information" macro (`\@extrainfo`) to `\relax`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@extrainfo\relax% Remove \@extrainfo
\makeatother
\makelettertitle
```

Answer (score 3):

add

```
\patchcmd\makelettertitle{\makenewline\@extrainfo}{}{}{}
```

after

```
\moderncvstyle{classic}
```

In more details, what this does is to edit `\makelettertitle` from `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` removing the call to `\@extrainfo`:

```
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
[...] 
     \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}} %% patchcmd edits this line removing the \@extrainfo command that is responsible for inserting the "additional information" inside the letter title
[...]
```

the `etoolbox` package (which allows you to use `patchcmd`) is already loaded by `moderncv` so you just need to use it.

Comment: How would I achieve the same result, but using the 'banking' style?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the easiest way would be to add an empty `\extrainfo{}` before the command `\makelettertitle`. Thereby you would overwrite the previous information.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title} 
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org} 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\clearpage
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}  
\extrainfo{}                    % <== that's the magic
\makelettertitle
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```