# extrainfo shall only appear in CV but not in cover letter

Tags: moderncv

In [`moderncv`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), I add the line

```
\extrainfo{\faPassport~MyNationality}
```

to the preamble.

**How can I let this information appear only on the CV but not on the cover letter?**

As per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145372/66974), this should be possible through

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\@extrainfo\relax
\makeatother
```

However, this lets `@extrainfo` disappear on both the cover letter and CV.

I attempted to fix this through

```latex
\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \let\@extrainfo\relax
    \makeatother
    \makelettertitle
\endgroup
```

however, this appears to overwrite other format settings: the left-aligned cover letter text becomes justified. I want to keep this default setting, though.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}           % encoding
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}         % language
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=20mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm
]{geometry}                       % specify margins

\firstname{FirstName}
\familyname{LastName}
\title{ProfileTitle}
\address{Street}{ZIP}{City}
\extrainfo{\faPassport~Nationality}
\mobile{\href{tel:+123456789}{+123456789}}
\email{some@mail.com}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/some-page]{some-page}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Copmany}{
    Street\\
    ZIP City\\
    Country
}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\closing{Sincerely,}

\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    % remove extrainfo from cover letter
    \let\@extrainfo\relax
    \makeatother
    % create letter title
    \makelettertitle
\endgroup

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

\makeletterclosing

\newpage
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `\extrainfo`  only before  `\makecvtitle`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}           % encoding
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}         % language
\usepackage[
a4paper,
left=25mm,
right=20mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm
]{geometry}                       % specify margins

\firstname{FirstName}
\familyname{LastName}
\title{ProfileTitle}
\address{Street}{ZIP}{City}
%\extrainfo{\faPassport~Nationality} % NOT HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\mobile{\href{tel:+123456789}{+123456789}}
\email{some@mail.com}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/some-page]{some-page}

\begin{document}
    
    \recipient{Copmany}{
        Street\\
        ZIP City\\
        Country
    }
    \date{\today}
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
    \closing{Sincerely,}

    \makelettertitle
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
    
    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
    
    Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
    
    \makeletterclosing
    
    \newpage
    
    \extrainfo{\faPassport~Nationality} % added <<<<<<<<<<<
    \makecvtitle
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: Well, that's an easy fix. Not my preferred solution, but it works fine. Thanks!